# How do I make GVM recognize my existing Grails and Groovy installations?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, gvm

I currently have set up Grails 2.3.0 and 2.3.11 inside `/opt` directory. How I avoid re-installing by making GVM recognize them as existing candidates?

Comment: i think simlink to `~/.gvm/grails/` will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move each of the directories to `~/.gvm/grails/<version>` (e.g. from `/opt/grails-2.4.3` to `~/.gvm/grails/2.4.3`) and symlink those back to `/opt`... or vice versa.

**EDIT for sdkman**

sdkman replaced GVM.  use `~/.sdkman` instead of `~/.gvm`

Comment: Thanks! Do I symlink all the files or the top directory? Can you `ls` and send me one of your `~/.gvm/grails/<version>`?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I have added an example, that should make this clear

Comment: Thanks! Got it now. when do I symlink to for my existing groovy installations?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Groovy is the same, but into `~/.gvm/groovy`.